# Invalid argument - root element

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, google-apps-script

I'm trying to modify an XML file on my Google Drive using :

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('keyWordsList.xml').next();
var xml = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
var root = document.getRootElement();
var child = XmlService.createElement('keyword');
var childName = XmlService.createElement('label').setText(name);
root.addContent(child);
document = XmlService.createDocument(root);
xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format();
DriveApp.createFile("keyWordsList.xml", xml);
```

This is a simplified example.
But `XmlService.createDocument(root);` throws an error :

> Invalid argument: rootElement

Comment: Yes it work. I found a new way to do if someone is intersest

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution if someone get the same problem.
You dont need to create the document for being accept by Google Drive

```
    var root = document.getRootElement();
    var child=  XmlService.createElement('keyword');
    var childName = XmlService.createElement('label').setText(name);
    var childKeyWord = child.addContent(childName);
    for(var x=0;x<keywords.length;x++)
    {
     childKeyWord = XmlService.createElement('motcle').setText(keywords[x]);
     child.addContent(childKeyWord);
    } 
    root.addContent(child); 
    var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(root);
    DriveApp.createFile("keyWordsList.xml",xml,"text/xml");
```